# sqlite3 задвоение результатов запроса

Tags: python, sqlite3, prettytable

```
import sqlite3
from prettytable import PrettyTable

DATABASE_NAME = 'drinks.sqlite3'

query = '''
SELECT Orders.date_, Drinks.name,
Orders.quantity, Drinks.price,
Orders.quantity * Drinks.price AS payment,
Clients.name
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Drinks
ON Orders.drink_id = Drinks.id
INNER JOIN Clients
ON Orders.client_id = Clients.id;
'''

with sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_NAME) as connection:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    for row in cursor.execute(query):
        print(row)
```

Есть вот такой модуль с запросом на выборку из БД, в котором забыл убрать ненужный здесь импорт PrettyTable. Происходит странное - результаты запроса задваиваются. Если импорт закомментировать или убрать - все работает как надо. Почему так?

Comment: А `prettytable` - это стандартная библиотека или ваш какой-то файл с кодом так называется?

Comment: @CrazyElf это https://pypi.org/project/prettytable/

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Это понятно, но вдруг у автора вопроса и его файл так же называется. Подобной причиной довольно много ошибок на СО объясняется.

Comment: файл так не называется))